# Looping HTML code inside php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want HTML code to repeat after every execution of `while()`. But it is not repeating.

Actually, I want that on every line it reads a box is made with comment and like button at the bottom. Therefore I kept HTML code inside `while` loop but after running the code after every execution line are written in same box.

Here is the code reference:

```
   <?php
        $name = $_POST['name']; 
        $query = $_POST["query"];
        $po = "$name-$query";
        $myfile = fopen("posts.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($myfile,$po);
        fclose($myfile);
        $mypost=fopen("posts.txt","r");
        while(!feof($mypost)): ?> <!-- with this while loop i want this div class to repeat --> 
    <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin"><br>
    <img src="/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
    <span class="w3-right w3-opacity">1 min</span>
            <h4>fdg</h4><br>
            <hr class="w3-clear">
            <p> <?php
            echo fgets($mypost);
            ?></p>
            <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  Like</button> 
            <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>  Comment</button> 
          </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Please help What can I do?

Comment: You can try: $po="$name-$querry\n"; But I do not know if this solves.

Comment: What does your posts.txt look like? I suppose you want data in lines.

Comment: You can also try: while($line = fgets($mypost)): and echo $line;

Comment: @halojoy \n helped to some extent along with 1st answer given by scaisEdge my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple why is using an echo of the related  string for html code in a php code block {}

```
 <?php
      $name = $_POST['name']; 
      $query = $_POST["query"];
      $po = "$name-$query"; 
      $myfile = fopen("posts.txt", "a+");
      fwrite($myfile,$po);
      fclose($myfile);
      $mypost = fopen("posts.txt","r");

      while(!feof($mypost)) {
        echo '<div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-round w3-margin"><br>
          <img src="/w3images/avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="w3-left w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:60px">
          <span class="w3-right w3-opacity">1 min</span>
            <h4>fdg</h4><br>
            <hr class="w3-clear">
            <p>'. fgets($mypost)
            . '</p>
            <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>  Like</button> 
            <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>  Comment</button> 
          </div>';
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: @sciasEdge add \n to this line $po="$name-$querry"; then it is working perfectly